# Jenkins workflow pass variable to shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I pass a variable e.g. `buildNumber`

```
sh 'gulp sometask --someOption="attribute=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"'
```

to the `sh` command using Jenkins workflow / pipeline?
My example unfortunately only yields a bad substitution error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

could you please try this command here:

`sh "gulp sometask --someOption='attribute=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'"`

The quotation marks are exchanged. I think the reason is, that you can templating with double quotes (using GString), which doesn't work with single quotes (using a plain String) in groovy.

for more information see the [Groovy Documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this command:

```
sh """gulp sometask --someOption='attribute=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'"""
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try

```
sh 'gulp sometask --someOption="attribute=${BUILD_NUMBER}"'
```

Comment: I tried to access e.g. echo the value but only in case of env.Build_number it was actually available in a pipeline / workflow environment